# what is the difference between 転ぶ【ころぶ】 and 落ちる【おちる】

Tags: words, word-usage, connotation

What is the difference between 転ぶ【ころぶ】 and 落ちる【おちる】?

Here is a nice entry about  おちる
[The differences with おちる (落ちる、堕ちる、墜ちる)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62495/31150)

...but I have not found an explanation of the difference between 転ぶ【ころぶ】 and 落ちる【おちる】 as it occurs in this sentence:

けがは「転【ころ】ぶ」が約【やく】40％、「落【お】ちる」が約【やく】30％で、この2つで約【やく】70%でした

which I would unidiomatically translate as

*About 40% were injured by tumbling and about 30% by dropping.*

https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10013371171000/k10013371171000.html

The wwwjdic entries for each verb give quite a number of suggestions, but I was wondering how to imagine the situations leading to the different kinds of injury. For instance, does one use 転【ころ】ぶ for "falling down stairs" and 落ちる【おちる】 for "falling off a ladder"?

Comment: After 落ちる, you usually end up somewhere else while you stay in the same place when 転ぶ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Definition 2](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%BB%A2%E3%81%B6_%28%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%81%B6%29/) for 転ぶ here defines it as 'to lose one's balance and fall down', while [落ちる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8B/) is defined as 'to naturally or suddenly move from above to below'. While *technically* you could say 落ちる is involved in 転ぶ - it is after all gravity pulling down after you lose your balance - in practice they're pretty separate. There's more of an element of height in the ladder compared to the stairs.

One more example: if you tripped and fell through a window, the initial tripping is 転ぶ, while what happens after you go through is 落ちる.

Comment: Wonderful imagery.  

Comment: Consider also the word associations -- 転【ころ】ぶ is closely related to words like ころころ, ころがる, etc. that involve actions like "tumbling" or "turning end over end".